# Photogravure: What is it?

Tags: printing, prints, alt-process

I was looking at some of Edward Steichen's work and see references to the printing process as "photogravure." What is it, it almost sounds like an intaglio process?

Answer (score 8):

I find that the [Wikipedia article on Photogravure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogravure) gives a good detailed overview of the subject. An easier to follow and shorter version can be found [in this description of the process](http://www.photogravure.com/process/process.html). Here's the summary of the technique:

1. Contact-print a positive onto a layer of gelatine sensitized in potassium dichromate. This hardens the exposed parts of the gelatine.
2. Transfer the gelatine layer onto a copper plate.
3. Soak this plate in hot water. This will dissolve the unexposed parts of the gelatine.
4. Etch the plate in a ferric chloride. Here the remaining gelatine slows the etching, resulting in smaller wells that will hold less ink in printing.
5. Make prints from the plate.

I have tried to create the following illustration that might help understanding the process:

[image: Photogravure steps illustrated]

As you can see, this means that photogravure is a form of [intaglio printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intaglio_%28printmaking%29), as the image is incised into a surface and the sunken areas hold the ink.

On a sidenote, [this article on Photogravure by the Getty Conservation Institute](https://www.getty.edu/conservation/publications_resources/pdf_publications/pdf/atlas_photogravure.pdf)  gives some historical background, discusses important variants, and also talks about identification of photogravure prints.

Finally, see also [Photoengraving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoengraving) for the more general family of processes related to photogravure.